# What are the practical use of weak semaphores?

Tags: concurrency, mutual-exclusion

Weak semaphores are often defined as

> if a process (or thread), say p1, performs a V operation and some
>   other process is waiting on that semaphore, then the first process
>   (i.e. p1) is not allowed to immediately perform another P operation on
>   that semaphore. Instead, one of the waiting processes must be given
>   its turn.

Further, while a single weak-semaphore cannot guarantee starvation-freedom, using few of them can actually guarantee starvation-freedom.
Can anyone mention any practical use of such weak-semaphores!

ǂ*The quoted section is from the paper "An Efficient Solution to the Mutual Exclusion Problem Using Weak Semaphores" by S. A. Friedberg and G. L. Peterson, with a bit of embellishment*

Comment: I have met FIFO semaphores before, but I've never seen such a weak form of semaphores in practice.